# `eb deploy` errors out with "Default subnet not found in us-west-2d"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, subnet, vpc

My application has worked in Elastic Beanstalk for years, and now, out of nowhere, when attempting to deploy I get the following error:

```
Upload Complete.
2019-04-30 22:44:21    INFO    Environment update is starting.
2019-04-30 22:44:44    ERROR   Service:AmazonCloudFormation, Message:Stack named 'awseb-e-2etmaatfsm-stack' aborted operation. Current state: 'UPDATE_ROLLBACK_IN_PROGRESS'  Reason: The following resource(s) failed to update: [AWSEBLoadBalancer].
2019-04-30 22:44:44    ERROR   Updating load balancer named: awseb-e-2-AWSEBLoa-13E02TCAOUR85 failed Reason: Default subnet not found in us-west-2d (Service: AmazonElasticLoadBalancing; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationError; Request ID: 8873a7c6-6b99-11e9-8d65-737139191d2f)
2019-04-30 22:44:44    ERROR   Failed to deploy application.
```

I've always been in `us-west-2` and have never encountered something like this. It seems that this is a new AZ, and maybe there's something in my application configuration that automatically attempts to deploy to each AZ, but doesn't have the appropriate infrastructure in this new one yet?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error you're receiving tells us that `us-west-2d` does not have a default subnet.  Subnets, including the default subnet, can be deleted and if we delete the default subnet for an availability zone, and a service we're using (in this case `AmazonElasticLoadBalancing`) is dependent on that default subnet, then we will receive this error.

To resolve it simply recreate the default subnet in that availability zone, in this case `us-west-2d`.  You can do this from the CLI with this command:

`aws ec2 create-default-subnet --availability-zone us-west-2d`

Comment: My pleasure! Glad it was helpful. Please accept it as the correct answer so others know it is the correct resolution to this issue.